# Compare Python dictionary with list as value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, steam

I am writing a parser bot for Steam that will keep track of which items come and go from a Steam user's inventory. I wrote a code that gets all the user's items and returns in the form of a dictionary with a nested list, where **KEY = USER NAME, VALUE = ITEM NAME AND ITS QUANTITY.** Now I need to compare Data1 and Data2 (updated data).

```
Data1 = {
            'user1': [('AWP', 1), ('DEAGLE', 2), ('AK-47', 3)], 
            'user2': [('MP-7', 1), ('KNIFE', 1), ('GLOVES', 1)]

        }

Data2 = {
              
            'user1': [('AWP', 1), ('DEAGLE', 2), ('AK-47', 3), ('M4A4', 1)], 
            'user2': [('MP-7', 1), ('KNIFE', 1), ('GLOVES', 1), ('GLOCK-18', 1)] 

        }
```

For example, a new item appears in Data2 and I need to write it to the third dictionary, keeping the key. The same must be done if items leave Data2 (it means that these items are no longer in the user's inventory).

```
Result = {
              
            'user1': [('M4A4', 1)], 
            'user2': [('GLOCK-18', 1)] 

        }
```

Comment: Do you have duplicate inventory items for a single user within the same data dictionary?

Comment: @chsws Yes, I have duplicate elements, but another function handles them and returns all duplicates to int ```[('AK-47', 3)]``` 3 - shows the number of items.

Comment: By new item, would you include if the number incremented in the tuple? I assume not, given the acceptance to the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sets`

```
result_addition = {d:list(set(Data2[d]) - set(Data1[d])) for d in Data2.keys()}
print(result_addition)

>> {'user1': [('M4A4', 1)], 'user2': [('GLOCK-18', 1)]}


result_missing = {d:list(set(Data1[d]) - set(Data2[d])) for d in Data2.keys()}
print(result_missing )

>> {'user1': [], 'user2': []}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def dict_diff(dict_1, dict_2):
    keys = set(dict_1.keys()).union(set(dict_2.keys()))
    result = {}
    for key in keys:
        if key not in Data1:
            result[key] = Data2[key]
            continue
        if key not in Data2:
            result[key] = Data1[key]
            continue
        
        diff1 = set(Data2[key]).difference(set(Data1[key]))
        diff2 = set(Data1[key]).difference(set(Data2[key]))
        
        
        result[key] = list(diff1.union(diff2))

    return result
                
    
dict_diff(Data1, Data2)
```